# Can a SettingsCommand call back to the Windows app?

Tags: c#, windows, xaml

I have a SettingsCommand in my C#/XAML Windows 8 app.  It works perfectly.  One of the options I provide is to allow the user to reset all of their data in the app.  This also works perfectly.

However, the actual XAML page that was being viewed when the user opened the settings charm needs to refresh itself.  Is there a way to make a call to the page that is currently open?  Or get a reference to it?  Or pass a reference of the page to the SettingsCommand?

Or even have the page recognize that the charms bar has been opened?  Like a "focused"/"unfocused" kind of event?

Or, would it be possible to just navigate to a specific page of my app FROM the SettingsCommand UserControl?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I just needed to reference:

Frame rootFrame = Window.Current.Content as Frame;
rootFrame.Navigate(typeof(MainPage));